# Substitution Method to Prove Inequalities for Recurrence

Tags: inequality, algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursion, substitution

Use the substitution method to show that recurrence

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + n + 1
```

implies that

```
T(n) ≤ C * n^2
```

as long as

```
C ≥ 1 and C ≥ T(1)
```

I am trying to figure out what C represents in this question. My professor left it ambiguous. I believe that C is the number of expansions made on the recurrence.

Also, assuming that C is the number of expansions, I am not sure how to solve for it without a provided base case.

The farthest I got was partially guessing the generalized equation. I have:

```
T(n) = T(n-C) + (C*n) + [SOME SUMMATION INVOLVING C]
```

I have not figured out what the summation should be- or even if one is required.

Any direction on what C might be and how to solve for it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please do not ask the same questions multiple times. You should have edited the already closed question with required details instead of asking it again.

Comment: Noted... Apologies. I am new here. I was under the impression that a "closed" question was permanently "closed."

Answer (score 2):

Let us prove it by induction on $n$. Clearly, $T(1) \leq C$ (it is one of the given assumptions).

Let us suppose that $T(n)  \leq Cn^{2}$. Then we have to prove that $T(n+1)\leq C(n+1)^{2}$.

Indeed, one has that
\begin{align*}
T(n+1) = T(n) + n + 1 & \leq Cn^{2} + n + 1\\\\
& \leq Cn^{2} + 2n + 1\\\\
& \leq C(n^{2}+2n+1) = C(n+1)^{2}
\end{align*}
because $C\geq 1$ by assumption. Therefore we are done.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Does this solution count as using the substitution method? I am required to use it for this problem.

Comment: I am not acquainted to such method, so I do not know if my solution fits the exigencies of your question.

Comment: @JohnStern This indeed does count as the substitution method.